# Beautiful Soup returns the same output over and over

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to web scraping. I want the scraper return all the paragraphs with the keyword "neuro", however when I run the code it seems to return the same output for all the iterations. Could you kindly point me out my mistake?

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re 

from time import sleep
from random import randint

url = "https://www.findamasters.com/masters-degrees/united-kingdom/?40w900"
results = requests.get(url)
info =[]  
page_number = np.arange(1,1219)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

for page in page_number:
    page = requests.get("https://www.findamasters.com/masters-degrees/united-kingdom/?40w900&PG=" + str(page))
    div = soup.find("p", string =re.compile('neuro'))

sleep(randint(2,10))

masters = pd.DataFrame({
    'info': div})
masters.to_csv('masters.csv')
```

But the only output I get is:

```
<p>It’s our mission to prolong and improve the lives of patients, and we seek to do this by conducting world-leading research in areas such as neuroscience, oncology, infectious diseases and more.</p>
<p>It’s our mission to prolong and improve the lives of patients, and we seek to do this by conducting world-leading research in areas such as neuroscience, oncology, infectious diseases and more.</p>
....
```

Comment: Fix your indentation. We need to know which parts of the script are inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Unless you're logged into the site, the URL redirects to the same generic page.

Comment: hallo Barmar many thanks for the hint - @Roman Vasillev - many thanks for this question and for using from time import sleep this is very interesting. I learn alot. Keep up the great project.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem. `BeautifulSoup` parase `results.text` and results are from the fixed url "https://www.findamasters.com/masters-degrees/united-kingdom/?40w900".

Thus change the code as follows.

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re 

from time import sleep
from random import randint

url = "https://www.findamasters.com/masters-degrees/united-kingdom/?40w900"
results = requests.get(url)
info =[]  
page_number = np.arange(1,1219)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

for page in page_number:
    page = requests.get("https://www.findamasters.com/masters-degrees/united-kingdom/?40w900&PG=" + str(page))
    results = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
    div = soup.find("p", string =re.compile('neuro'))

sleep(randint(2,10))

masters = pd.DataFrame({
    'info': div})
masters.to_csv('masters.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, I tried your code and it returned: raise InvalidURL(*e.args)
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: <Response [200]>. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: The url you entered is invalid. Check the url is valid.